# Submitting apps to app store for iOS9

Tags: swift, ios9

I have been trying to submit my app multiple times to the app store and I keep seeing this error:

> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftPassKit.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, libswiftContacts.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreData.dylib, libswiftAVFoundation.dylib don’t match
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftPassKit.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib. Make sure
>   the files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it. Don’t apply
>   post-processing to
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftPassKit.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.

Is there something else i'm doing wrong? Or is it still not available? I'm not able to find any resources to help with the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's an issue with `Cocoapods`. As per below:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4188

The current latest version of Cocoapods is 0.39 beta 4 which does NOT work.

Comment: Cocoapods released 0.39 beta 5 which works with Xcode 7 and iOS 9.

Comment: Is that the latest one? I did install cocoapods and still having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your

```
Build Settings -> Embedded Content Contains Swift Code.
```

If it's NO,you can set it to YES,and then have a try.If it's not working.You can update your Mac system to Mac OS X 10.10.5 and your Xcode to Xcode 7,just rebuild your project with iOS 9,and then Xcode will tell you which you must deal with.